# When does $c\Bbb{Z}_n$ have a unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

In a ring $R$ with unity and subring $S$ with unity, in general, $1_S \ne 1_R$. This can be illustrated with $R = \Bbb{Z}_{10}$ and $S = 2\Bbb{Z}_{10}$, where $1_R = 1$ and $1_S = 6$.

To what extent can this example be generalized using subrings of $\Bbb{Z}_n$?  To be precise, for which values of $c$ and $n$ does the subring $c\Bbb{Z}_n$ of $\Bbb{Z}_n$ have a unity, and which element is it?

Comment: Usually a subring with unity $S\subset R$ refers to one that contains $1_R$.

Comment: @anomaly: In my experience, people who follow the convention that "ring" means a structure that has a unit, then homomorphisms (and thus subrings) are required to preserve the unit. But for the people who follow the convention that "ring" doesn't require a unit in its structure, when they consider the subclass of rings that do happen to have a unit, they do not require homomorphisms (and thus subrings) to preserve it.

Comment: It is unclear to me what additional context is desired to improve this question.  It is a natural question of general interest whose motivation is already explained in the post.

Comment: I agree; I don't know why it was closed, considering it already has an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $c\Bbb{Z}_n = d\Bbb{Z}_n$, where $d=\gcd(n,c)$.

A unit in $d\Bbb{Z}_n$ is an element $dz$ such that $dzdx \equiv dx \bmod n$ for all $x$.

It is enough that $dzd \equiv d \bmod n$, or $dz \equiv 1 \bmod n'$, where $n'=n/d$.

Such a $z$ exists iff $\gcd(d,n')=1$.